# Is there any word for referring to expired and/or voided subscriptions?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I'm modeling a service and I want to name expired and/or voided subscriptions (by either side, publisher or subscriber). Terms like "expired subscription" or "invalid subscription" didn't satisfy me. Now I'm asking if there is any better term for that? (Or I'm wrong and "expired ..." or "invalid ..." are good and rational words for this meaning!)

Comment: I guess it depends what you want to include. Expired subscriptions will be the most common old / invalid ones. However, there are certainly other reasons for a subscription to end which expired may not adequately cover.

Comment: Why not "closed"? It suggests only that the subscription was once "open", or valid, without specifying a reason for closure.

Comment: I'm a little hesitant about this, hence a comment rather than an answer. "Expired subscription" and "voided subscription" sound like oxymorons - if they're expired or voided, they're no longer subscriptions. The alternative terms *lapsed subscription* and *cancelled subscription* sound better to my ear, but appear to suffer from the same problem. If you're just after popular usage, Ngram may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [***discontinued***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discontinued) will suit.

> to cease to take, use, subscribe to, etc.:
> *to discontinue a newspaper.*

Reference:
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discontinued

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions can expire, so your term "expired subscription" is perfectly alright and commonly used. You should prefer that to "invalid".

[See this Microsoft page as one of thousands of examples where "expire" is used.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151188.aspx)